# How to look for a value in a hash?

Tags: string, perl, hash, key

I have a hash like

```
%has  = ('TCA' =>'S', 'TTC'=>'N'....)
```

and a

```
$string = 'TCA'
```

I want to look for my `$string` in the `%has` and if it exist,  print the value using perl like this:

```
TCA, S
```

How can I do that? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the value exists.

```
if (exists $has{$string}) {
     printf "%s, %s\n", $string, $has{$string};
}
```

Keep in mind that this is case sensitive.

You should probably read up on the various Perl functions in [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)

Comment: Note that the `exists` here isn't strictly required; if you access a hash element that doesn't exist, Perl returns `undef`...but also adds that key to the hash. If you care about the keys not changing when you want to access a hash element, use `exists`; if you don't, just access.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon That is incorrect. You are thinking of autovivification, which only occurs when you refer to a multidimensional structure. If you for example try to access `$has{foo}{bar}`, it will create `$has{foo}` if it does not already exist.

Comment: *forehead slap* You're quite right. Thank you! Although the comment re `exists` is still correct.

Comment: @JoeMcMahon Well, not entirely. `$has{$string}` can still be defined, but false, e.g. `0` or the empty string. `exists` is the safest check to perform, possibly one can also use `defined`.

Comment: True. I am in a maze of twisty little exceptions, all different. For the OP's example, with only string-valued values, a "is the key present" check would work, but as you say, there's always the chance that something didn't get initialized right, and `exists()` definitely tells you that there's a key-value pair there. Whether you got it right or not is of course not something we can guarantee without doing a `tie` or something more complex.